# Inserting a ContentVersion using Angularjs $http

Tags: angularjs, curl, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-chatter

I have been trying to insert files using Salesforce Chatter [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) but its been documented for curl. I am unable to find how to do the same in Angularjs using $http with visualforce. I am not able to set the request header and body properly. Please provide the header and body contents for the request, if this has to be done using javascript rather than curl.

#### Example for creating a new Document

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Document/ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer token"
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=\"boundary_string\""
--data-binary @newdocument.json
```

#### Example request body for creating a new Document

This code is the contents of `newdocument.json`. The binary data for the PDF content has been omitted for brevity and replaced
with “Binary data goes here.” An actual request contains the full binary content.

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_document";
Content-Type: application/json

{
"Description" : "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011",
"Keywords" : "marketing,sales,update",
"FolderId" : "005D0000001GiU7",
"Name" : "Marketing Brochure Q1",
"Type" : "pdf"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="2011Q1MktgBrochure.pdf"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

Comment: Try using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Also be sure to [Use CORS to Access Salesforce Resources from Web Browsers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/extend_code_cors.htm).